# Problem when intersecting two arrays in C

Tags: c

Newbie programmer here, I'm from Brazil so sorry for my bad English, I had this exercise in college in which I had to make two arrays, one with 10 positions and another with 20 positions, then make the union and the intersection between them.
The union went well, could make it faster than I thought, but the intersection has been causing me trouble for some good hours, and I can't find where I'm missing the code until now, thanks for any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int r[10];
    int s[20];
    int x[30];
    int y[10];
    
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        r[i] = rand() % 10;
        printf("\nR -Esse é a posição %d, com o numero %d", i + 1, r[i]);
    } 
    
    printf("\n--------------------------------------\n");
    
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        s[i] = rand() % 20;
        printf("\nS - Esse é a posição %d, com o numero %d", i + 1, s[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n--------------------------------------\n");
    
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
        x[i] = r[i];
    
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        x[i + 10] = s[i];
        printf("\nX -Esse é a posição %d, com o numero %d", i + 1, x[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n--------------------------------------\n");
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if (r[i] == s[j]) {
                printf("\nY -Essa é a posição %d, com o numero %d", i + 1, r[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can post the question (and receive answers) in Portuguese on [pt.so]. Você pode postar a pergunta (e receber respostas) em português no [pt.so].

Comment: You might want to think about what "union" and "intersect" really mean. In mathematics, there are "union" and "intersection" of sets. Is this what you really want to implement? I think not! You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the fact that your integer range is limited to values between 0-19. That is, you'll never assign a value in `r` to anything larger than 9. And you won't assign anything in `s` to anything larger than 19.

After initializing `r[10]` and `s[20]` exactly as you have them, declare a table array to keep track of which values you've seen before.  Since the range of integers in `r` an `s` are between 0 and 19, this is an easy declaration:

```
int table[20] = {0};  // initialize array to all zeros
```

Then initialize `table` using r and s. Look for duplicates too:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   int value = r[i];
   table[value] = 1; // set a "1" to indicate we've seen this value before
}

for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
   int value = s[j];
   int has_seen_before = table[value] ? 1 : 0;
   table[value] = has_seen_before ? 2 : 1;
}
```

After the above two loops complete. For any index, k. If `table[k]==2` then k appears both arrays. if `table[k] == 1`, then it only appears in one array.

Then intersection is this:

```
int intersection[10] = {0};
int intersection_count = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    if (table[k] == 2) {
        intersection[intersection_count] = k;
        intersection_count++;
    }
}
```

When the above loop is done, `intersection` holds all the values in both arrays.  Then length of the array is specified by `intersection_count`;

Union is similar

```
int unionArray[20] = {0};
int union_count = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
    if (table[k] > 1) {
        unionArray[union_count] = k;
        union_count++;
    }
}
```